# Position-absolute element not showing

Tags: html, css

I want the child element to be displayed right under the parent element, just like when you input tags on stack overflow you can see a list of tag suggestions listed below the input bar. However, the suggestions box element does not show up, while I could see that the element was there at the expected position when inspecting the page. I am wondering how to fix the issue.

**html**

```
              <div className="tags-input-bar">
                ......
                {this.state.suggestedTags.length !== 0 ? 
                <div className="suggestions-box">
                    {this.state.suggestedTags && this.state.suggestedTags.map((tag) => {
                      return <button id={tag} onClick={this.addTag}>{tag}</button>
                    })}
                 </div>
                 : null }
              </div>
```

**css**

```
.tags-input-bar {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.suggestions-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.tags-input-bar has only height of 50px so absolute property always depended on the parent element's relative position so it will go "bottom:-80px" under the parent element.

so wrap with a div element with position property relative and remove  position from .tags-input-bar.

feel free ask for clarity,i have posted the possible solution below

```
     <div style='position:relative'>
<div className="tags-input-bar">//remove relative from here
                ......
                {this.state.suggestedTags.length !== 0 ? 
                <div className="suggestions-box">
                    {this.state.suggestedTags && this.state.suggestedTags.map((tag) => {
                      return <button id={tag} onClick={this.addTag}>{tag}</button>
                    })}
                 </div></div>
                 : null }
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your combination of setting for .suggestions-box needs work.  As it is, the parent DIV is only 50px high, with no overflow-y setting (and I'm not sure absolute positioning affects overflow).  Your settings tell the browser to make the .suggestions-box 80px high, but position the bottom 80px *BELOW* the bottom of the parent DIV.  Was your intent to show the .suggestions-box fully below the parent?  Absolute positioning is *not* what you want to do to accomplish that.  Why mess with this at all?  Just allow the .suggestions-box contents to be displayed after/below the rest of the contents in .tags-input-bar